# Batch File to move files with a Specific String to a Specific Folder

Tags: batch-file

I am trying to create a .bat file to move the files with the specific string to a specific folder.
For Ex. `C:\Test`
in this Test Folder there are several files like:

```
test-101.txt
test-102.doc
```

Also I have created the folder D:\Destination and in that several folders such as:

```
test-101
test-102
```

I want to match the string `'test-101'` and move it to folder `'test-101'`. Same for `'test-102.doc'` it will move to `test-102`. I have thousands of files like that and folders too, so I cannot write the name of the file or folder in script. Please tell me the solution to match and move the files automatically. I have tried several strings and it only moves the file with specified name in batch file.

Comment: What is the range of the numbers after the word "test"? I mean, have you got files starting with "Test99..." or "Test4000000..."?

Comment: Are the files all in one original folder, or are they in sub-folders?

Comment: Do you really want to move the files? Or copy them (so the originals remain where they were)?

Comment: Why don't you write a program instead of writing a batch file? It will be much better to handle exceptions using a program. Writing such a program will only take few minutes!

Answer (score 2):

No batch script required.

If the destination folders already exist, then

```
for %F in (c:\test\*) do move "%F" "d:\destination\%~nF\" >nul
```

If the destination folders may not exist yet, then

```
for %F in (c:\test\*) do (md "d:\destination\%~nF"&move "%F" "d:\destination\%~nF\") >nul
```

If you do end up using this code within a batch script, then don't forget to double up all the percents.

Answer (score 0):

```dos
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SETLOCAL ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION
SET "sourcedir=c:\sourcedir"
SET "destdir=c:\destdir"
FOR /f "delims=" %%a IN (
 'dir /b /a-d "%sourcedir%\*" '
 ) DO (
 ECHO MD "%destdir%\%%~na"
 ECHO MOVE "%sourcedir%\%%a" "%destdir%\%%~na\"
)
GOTO :EOF
```

The required MD commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MD` to `MD` to actually create the directories. Append `2>nul` to suppress error messages (eg. when the directory already exists)

The required MOVE commands are merely `ECHO`ed for testing purposes. **After you've verified that the commands are correct**, change `ECHO MOVE` to `MOVE` to actually move the files.  Append `>nul` to suppress report messages (eg. `1 file moved`)

Note also that if the source and destination are on different drives, you may need to `COPY /B` the files rather than `MOVE`ing them. You'd no doubt also need to delete the file from its original location.